# Responding to dynamically created async postback buttons

Tags: asynchronous, updatepanel, scriptmanager

When my ASP page is loaded I am reading data from a SQL database into a list of objects, then looping through this list and creating dynamic placeholders, updatepanels, textboxs and buttons which are then added to a main placeholder. Each updatepanel is set to conditional and the unique button is added to the scriptmanager. I tried to create async triggers dynamically but found this is not possible. Below is my code:

```
Dim plcComments As New PlaceHolder()
plcComments.ID = "plcComments" + Link.ID.ToString()

Dim updComments As New UpdatePanel()
updComments.ID = "updComments" + Link.ID.ToString()
updComments.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional

Dim txtComment As New TextBox()
txtComment.ID = "txtComment" + Link.ID.ToString()
txtComment.Text = "txtComment " + Link.ID.ToString() 'Example text
updComments.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(txtComment)

Dim btnComment As New Button()
btnComment.ID = "btnComment" + Link.ID.ToString()
btnComment.Text = "btnComment" + Link.ID.ToString()
updComments.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(btnComment)
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnComment)

plcComments.Controls.Add(updComments)
```

In a normal circumstance I understand you would have code behind for each button that acts a trigger. As these buttons are created dynamically with unique names, how can I react to each button when it is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the AddHandler function I came up with this dirty method:

```
AddHandler btnComment.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Handler
```

This latches to each button as it is created, points back at the same sub routine, and creates the controls within the subroutine based upon the sender.

```
Protected Sub Button_Handler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim Comment_ID As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).ID.ToString.Remove(0, 3)

    Dim txtComment As TextBox = Me.FindControl("txt" & Comment_ID)
    Dim plcComment As PlaceHolder = Me.FindControl("plc" & Comment_ID)
    Dim updComment As UpdatePanel = Me.FindControl("upd" & Comment_ID)

End Sub
```

Probably not the cleanest or best way to do it but it works.